# Login Facebook Oauth2 return empty data

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

When I try to login using facebook in last step it return empty data my first stip is using these link to get code

https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=216021238137351&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7258/api/Authentication/callback&auth_type%20=%20rerequestscope=email%20read_insights%20public_profile%20business_management%20pages_read_user_content%20user_photos

then I put the code that I get from previous link in the next link

https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=216021238137351&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7258/api/Authentication/callback&client_secret=662c36c1d253167865a7d60522bfafe6&code=

finally I put access token in the next link

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=

and this what response look like

Comment: Are the pages the user has, _business_ pages? If not, you'd need `pages_show_list` permission.